# Nearest Neighbor without outliers in 2d point cloud

Tags: c++, algorithm, nearest-neighbor, point-clouds, outliers

I am trying to find correspondances between a point (let say a detection) in a point cloud at time t and another point in a point cloud at time T != t to estimate the motion of the point (speed and orientation) in a ROS node (we do not have detections at time T so I have to find which can be the point of the detection in an immediately past/future frame). 
The problem is that for the time being I am using a simple nearest neighbor approach in a certain radius, i.e.

```
for all detections P at t
   for all points of the PC at time T
       take all points in PC within the radius R
       find the nearest to P
       compute velocity and orientation according to the different timestamps of t and T
```

My problem is that by using this very naive approach a get satisfiable solution only if the detection point and the corresponding cloud are well distant from other points ( basically if no noisy alone points are in the radius). 
What I was looking for is a method to find the nearest neighbor point discarding the outliers which can provide a non feasible orientation and speed module for the motion of the object. 
 So, basically doing something like that:

```
for all detections P at t
   for all points of the PC at time T
     take all points in PC within the radius R
     compute all the distances from such points to P and discard the outliers
     find the group of points which has "similar" distance (even if not the minimum)
     compute the centroid of such points
     use the centroid to compute speed and orientation
```

The problem is that I cannot figure out how to do it in c++. Maybe there are some function already implemented in BOOST which can help me? 
I was thinking about sorting the distances from all the points in the radius to the detection and discard the last and the first but this is not a good way to proceed I guess and furthermore if I sort the vector of distances I will no more be able to retrieve the points corresponding to each distance. 
Hope I explained the problem well, if not I am sorry. 
What I would need should be a Nearest Neighbor algorithm capable of discarding the noisy points/outliers in the search range.

[image: This is how my point cloud looks like]

This is an example of point cloud and the two small clouds on the top left of the car are 2 pedestrians walking.

Comment: Could you post an image of what an input "cloud" looks like?

Comment: I added the image... <br> Anyway I cannot figure out how a neural network could be useful in my case.

Comment: how do you differentiate between points at t and points at T? If you don't have T point, how do you want to use them in your loop (`for all points of the PC at time T`)?

Comment: @J.Chomel I keep a buffer of size 3 with the last 3 laser scans in a callback, so I know the timestamps of each laser scan in the buffer. Since I do not have a detection at each time since they come from image processing, the detection points instead are asynchronous, but again I know their timestamps. For avoiding numerical issues, now I am comparing the points of the laser scan contained in the buffer that have the wider time interval from the detection.

Comment: Have you tried the `PointCloudLibrary` (PCL) as suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20269594/remove-outlier-in-point-cloud

Comment: @J.Chomel Yes I have already seen that post but I am dealing with 2d point clouds and that kind of filters work only with PointXYZ types. I tried the workaround to set every point z equal to 0.0 but anyway this is not like using directly PointXY clouds regarding the computation time. Moreover is quite difficult to find the right values to feed the filter. However I am trying to use the approach suggested in the link you posted to see if the results can improve. For now they are not good at all.

Answer (score 1):

It is a very peculiar kind of cloud of points you want to apply your algorithm to.

This is where your reasoning goes wrong:

> and furthermore if I sort the vector of distances I will no more be able to retrieve the points corresponding to each distance.

With the appropriate structure, you can track vectors and close points for each point.

Let's say you have a point with neighbors (`n1`,`n2`,..) and associated distances (`d1`, `d2`,...) like this:

```
point
 ---> n1, d1
 ---> n2, d2
 ---> n3, d3
 ---> n4, d4
```

This means each point has a `vector` (c object, not movement) of `pair` of (point, distance). Here is how you could implement it:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class mPoint
{
  public:
    mPoint();

  private:
    int x;
    int y;
    std::vector<std::pair<mPoint, float>> neighbors;    
};    
...
```

Then C++ is great to compute and play with objects around.
Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your hint. I am doing so but the problem still remains. What I figured out in order to filter out some outliers is to use both a vector of distances and orientations. Then, in some way, find the most feasible orientation based on the number of points that have similar orientations and compute then the point of such group with minimum distance from the detection. In this way, if a point is the nearest to my detection point but has an orientation totally different from the major part of points in the radius, I'll discard it.